# What is the pipeline for a project that needs Cycles renders for still images and Eevee renders for animation?

Tags: rendering

Is there a way to achieve this in a non destructive way, having both settings on the same project?
At the moment, the only solution I see to this is just to having the project completely finished and then duplicate it for the different render settings, because the outputs are fundamentally different.
I am using mostly the HDRI image as a source of light, and I think this is sending Eevee crazy: in fact I need to disable the World in the viewport, or everything looks almost white.

Comment: You can make your Cycles objects first and then bake the lighting and shadows into the textures - you can then apply those (pre-baked) textures to your objects and render the scene in eevee.

Comment: Um, I'll search for documentation about this, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Material output can luckily be directed to one or the other rendering engine, so one can easily compensate for the lighting limiations of Eevee by using a different output material on the same shader graph.
This helps greatly by not requiring to add and switch materials in the objects, it all happens inside the same material node graph, and also projection, images nodes etc. can be shared.

[image]